# Constraints in Closed Type Families

Tags: haskell

I feel like 100 questions like this have already been asked, but I can't determine the answer from them: I learned the following Haskell (7.8.4) trick:

```
type family Equal2 (a :: k) (b :: k) :: Bool where
  Equal2 a a = True
  Equal2 a b = False
```

which can be used to compile code separately depending on whether "a ~ b".

Is it possible to extend this technique to other constraints like matching a typeclass? It feels like it's close to being possible, but not quite there.

Comment: Do you want to figure out if something is an instance of a type class or do you want to see if two type classes are equal?

Comment: Sadly, the former. I think the latter's pretty achievable.

Comment: You might be interested in the `constraints` package. It isn't exactly the same as what you're talking about but, depending on what you need it for, it might be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean to replace `a ~ b` by something like `Ord a` or the like:

No, it is not possible, because while Haskell can test whether datatypes are *equal*, it has no concept of a datatype being definitely *not* in a *typeclass* - you can always add an instance in another module which this one doesn't know about. This is known as the "open world assumption".

Answer (score 1):

With [ConstraintKinds](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html) you can compute constraints from types, as this silly example shows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

type family CustomConstraint (a :: k) (b :: k) :: Constraint where
  CustomConstraint a a = Show a
  CustomConstraint a b = ()

data Unshowable = MkUnshowable

f :: (CustomConstraint a b) => a -> b -> ()
f _ _ = ()

-- Well-typed, because the constraint is ()
x = f True MkUnshowable

-- Ill-typed, because the constraint is Show Unshowable
y = f MkUnshowable MkUnshowable
```

Is this the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: You can simplify this a little by making the first `type family` equation equal to something like `Char ~ Bool`.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't quite figured out how I'd apply it, but it looks useful.